# ¿Como puedo capturar el ID de un textbox y usarlo en un javascript para abrir un modal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estoy intentando capturar el ID de 31 textbox y que abra un modal si es que tiene texto dentro

```
<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control test" style="padding: 0px 0px;width: 36px; font-size: 11.5px;" ReadOnly onclick="mostrar(this.ID)"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
  <asp:TextBox class="form-control test" ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="padding: 0px 0px;width: 36px; font-size: 11.5px;" ReadOnly onclick="mostrar(this.ID)"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Este es mi JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function mostrar(ID){
    var product = document.getElementById('ID').value;
     if (product != "") {
     $('#\\myModal').modal('show');
     }
   }
</script>
```

Este es mi modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

No logro que se despliegue el modal, alguna idea de como lograrlo

Comment: La linea del modal esta mal `$('#\\myModal').modal('show');`, debería ser algo asi: `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

Answer (score 3):

[editado] bueno, dentro de los paréntesis no va "ID", sino va el id de tu textbox... Osea:

```
document.getElementById('TextBox1').value
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es obtener el id del elemento al que le diste click como dices en el comentario, mediante jquery podrías usar esta función:

```
$("Textbox").click(function() {
    var oID = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Comment: Incluso al ser un `id` se puede hacer referencia directamente con el nombre `TextBox1.value` sin necesidad del `document.getElementById`

Comment: Cierto, para eso existe "document.getElementByTagName('Textbox').value" o "document.getElementByName('nombre del la caja de texto').value"

Comment: En este caso, lo que mando es el ID de manera dinamica, porque tengo varios textbox y cada texbox tiene un ID único.

A mi funcion mostrar mando el ID de la caja de texto a la cual le doy click. Pero me aparece un error: value of null.

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta, espero pueda servirte

Answer (score 0):

Lo logré de esta manera

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mostrar(ID) {
     var  product = document.getElementById(ID.id).value;
     if (product != "") {
     $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
     }
  }
</script>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="#myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Textbox

```
<td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control test" style="padding: 0px 0px;width: 36px; font-size: 11.5px;" ReadOnly  onclick="mostrar(this)" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
   <asp:TextBox class="form-control test" ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="padding: 0px 0px;width: 36px; font-size: 11.5px;" ReadOnly onclick="mostrar(this)"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```